# Can't get max result of spot price history - US-EAST region

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

When I retrieve the history price of spot for "us-east-f1" or any region in "us-east-1", the result always less than 200 price, I need for single region and single instance type.
How can I retrieve a huge number of results?
EX:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
t=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(0)
f=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(90)
response= ec2.describe_spot_price_history(InstanceTypes =['c3.4xlarge'],ProductDescriptions = ['Linux/UNIX'], AvailabilityZone = 'us-east-1a', StartTime= f, EndTime = t, MaxResults=1000)
response =response['SpotPriceHistory']
```

I mean for a single region and instance type, I need the max result to be larger than this.

**Edit:**

I use paginator to get all result for all available pages:

```
paginator = ec2.get_paginator('describe_spot_price_history') 
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(StartTime= t, EndTime = f, MaxResults=2000 ) 
for page in page_iterator: 
   output = page['SpotPriceHistory']
```

However, I still get the same number of results! When I fetch the results of 90 days, I still got have the same amount of results?
How to get all results or to get the max amount of price values?

Comment: How do you know that more results exist?

Comment: You mean it return what history is there

Comment: How to access another region while I have permission only for us-east region. to get more result

Comment: It can happens that there is little price spike for particular AZ.

Comment: @mootmoot, How to access another region?

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/ec2-example-regions-avail-zones.html

Comment: all of them us-east-1 and for a single region and type I can't retrieve large amount of result :(

Comment: @Hana90 describe_spot_price_history is paginated.  You *might* need to capture the `NextToken` and repeat the request.  I don't believe this call is expected to always return `MaxResults` items per response, even if `MaxResults` items are available -- subsequent requests may be required in order to get more data.

Comment: @Hana90  I just try out, it seems boto3 `describe_availability_zone` either contains bugs or untold features, I cannot list the AZ outside my default region.  however,  the aws cli looks fine, e.g. `aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-west-1` .  Please post your describe-availability-zones issue here  : https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues  .

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to be working just fine, but the start and end timestamps were backwards.

I ran this code:

```
import boto3
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(90)
end_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(0)

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
paginator = ec2.get_paginator('describe_spot_price_history') 
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(InstanceTypes =['c3.4xlarge'],ProductDescriptions = ['Linux/UNIX'], AvailabilityZone = 'us-east-1a', StartTime= start_date, EndTime = end_date, MaxResults=2000 ) 

for page in page_iterator: 
   print page['SpotPriceHistory']
```

I got back one page that had 122 entries.

The first entry was for 2018-04-01:

```
{u'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018,
    4,
    1,
    4,
    40,
    44, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a', u'InstanceType': 'c3.4xlarge', u'ProductDescription': 'Linux/UNIX', u'SpotPrice': '0.840000'
},
```

The last entry was for 2018-01-02:

```
{u'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018,
    1,
    2,
    0,
    28,
    35, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a', u'InstanceType': 'c3.4xlarge', u'ProductDescription': 'Linux/UNIX', u'SpotPrice': '0.840000'
}
```

This cover the maximum 90 days of data that is available.

Comment: Yes, I got the similar number, can I get more than this? Is it impossible to access longer than 90 days :( ?

Comment: Correct. The [DescribeSpotPriceHistory documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSpotPriceHistory.html) says that the **StartTime** can be **up to the past 90 days**.

Answer (score 1):

To make an API call to another region, specify the `region_name`:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```

When `MaxResults` is exceeded, obtain the next set of results by making the same call, but set `NextToken` to the value returned by `NextToken` in the previous result set.

Comment: How to access previous 12 months?

Comment: Spot Price history is only available for the previous 90 days.

Comment: For more result, I use the following: paginator = ec2.get_paginator('describe_spot_price_history')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(StartTime= t, EndTime =  f, MaxResults=2000 )
for page in page_iterator: output = page['SpotPriceHistory']

Comment: is that will access nextoken? or I need to access it with another way? could u plz help me in this way?

Comment: You can either use a paginator, or you can call the normal method again, passing a `NextToken` value.

Comment: HOw? from where i can get the NextToken

Comment: So, paginator is a right way to access all pages? But still i have a same number of result as i call the same history method

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. Feel free to Edit your question to add details (eg what you are receiving vs what you are expecting).